# Python independent calculation of element lists in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Not sure how to describe the issue in exact sense...**

Is trying to create a function that returns multiple filtered element lists:

```
def search_test():
find = [('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
abc = [1,6,15]
result = []
for i in abc:              
    for j in range(len(find)):  # <-  How to loop through the individual element list? 
        if float(find[j][0]) * float(find[j][1]) <= i:
            result.append(i)
return(result)
        
print(search_test())
```

Basically, the function expect to calculate the product of values from `find` then compare it with list `abc`. If the product is greater than elements in `abc` then append to a new list called `result`

currently the result I get is `[6,15,15]` however the expecting the output to be `[[6,15],[15]]`. On the other words is that the function currently considering values in `find` as whole instead of two independent lists of their own element values.

The idea of the function is supposed to be:

[image]

So are there any ways to access the individual element lists to perform further calculation(s) then append to a new list as multiple sub-lists?

Comment: Why `[6, 15]`? Is not clear what that represents?

Comment: Yes sure. Add a [] into result. Add your numbers into result[-1].append(i) - but it is quite unclear what you are doing here#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not clearly mentioned whats need to be achieved here but as per my understanding you interchanged the for loops.
It seems you want to know what elements of **abc** satisfy the condition for each tuple in **find**. So first for loop should be on **find**
After that you need to create **result** list for each element in **find** and append that list to **final_result**

```
def search_test():
find = [('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
abc = [1, 6, 15]
final_result = []
for j in range(len(find)):
    result = []
    for i in abc:
        if float(find[j][0]) * float(find[j][1]) <= i:
            result.append(i)
    final_result.append(result)
return (final_result)
```

Comment: Thanks having a list inside the loop then append to the list outside solved the problem.